# ChangeTracker.DetectChanges() is not fixing up associations after a save using Breeze

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

In my entity framework layer I have validation that happens during SaveChanges. In my override of SaveChanges I call `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` and the fixup that I expect to happen doesn't occur when saving with Breeze.

Example: I have two entities Foo and Bar, with Bar having a reference to Foo. When I create and save both Foo and Bar at the same time in my context I can see both exists in their respective local list of their DbSets. In Bar, FooId is set to -1 which is the corresponding Id of the created Foo. Before DetectChanges is called I see that Bar.Foo is null yet after the call it is still null.

Is there something I'm missing for the relationship fixup to occur?

Comment: Sorry, need more info on this one...  or contact breeze@ideablade.com for support options.

Comment: What info do you need?